# How can I get ConnectionString Name from config file

Tags: c#

I can read the connection strings from the config file, however I need to get the element name that is associated with connection string.

Example

```
<connectionStrings>
<add 
  name="LocalSqlServer" 
  connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"   />
 </connectionStrings>
```

I need to get LocalSqlServer out of the connectionString.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) it should work like this:

```
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connections = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

if (connections.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connection in connections)
    {
        string name = connection.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: No OP wants to get `LocalSqlServer`.

Comment: Yeah, i saw that a second after my answer. I changed it.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name
```

Comment: If ConfigurationManager is not available for you, you could add it by right clicking `References>Add Reference` and adding `System.Configuration`

Answer (score 2):

You access it programmatically through the API.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx